# @Autowired a class member in Java @Configuration file

Tags: java, spring, autowired

in these days i'm studying how to define beans with Spring Core, in the XML file and/or the Java notation. These methods seem equivalent, but are they still so if we add the following condition?

- It is not possible to change the class file.

In this case, everything written in the XML file should be written in the AppConfig file (the one in which the class has the `@Configuration` annotation).

Sadly i found a counterexample: setting a class member (an attribute) with the autowire. While it is possible to precede the class member definition with the `@Autowired` annotation, that's not the case when using only the Java configuration file.

```
@Component
public class Foo{
    @Autowired
    private Bar bar;
}
```

The following code in fact is wrong:

```
public class AppConfig{
    @Bean
    Foo foo(){
         Foo foo = new Foo();
         @Autowired
         Bar foo.bar ?? ;
         return foo;
    }
}
```

I've already searched every documentation and every question, but I'm still in confusion about this topic.

Comment: just define `@Autowired Bar bar` outside of the method `foo()` and then set when creating the `Foo` object

Comment: Use `Foo foo(Bar bar)` as the method, Spring will detect the dependency and inject it in the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the method `Foo foo()` accept the `Bar bar` as the parameter. Spring framework recognizes the bean instance available by its type to be injected. Beware of more bean instances of `Bar`, then the [`@Qualifier`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) must be used to differentiate them and inject the correct one. There is no need to use [`@Autowired`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) again.

```
@Bean
Foo foo(Bar bar){
     Foo foo = new Foo();
     foo.method(bar);      // Or whatsoever...
     return foo;
}
```

Read more at D-Zone article about [injecting beans in Spring](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-configuration-and), it might help.

Comment: Thanks, until now i thought that parameters in `foo(Bar bar)` were just for constructors in the class `Foo`, also the article is very good!